# Where is login action for ASP.NET Web API 2, Owin, and Identity authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I am using token based authentication for my application whose client side is angularjs, by following [this tutorial](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)

I can see that configuration is done in Startup.Auth.cs via this code snippet

```
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
```

But I am looking for where is the Login Action, I suppose it should be somewhere in side AccountController.

Once user is authenticated I will be checking regarding its user role and assign some session variables

Where can I do this initial works?

Answer (score 2):

After following my research I found [this link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api) by Mike Wasson:

[image]

in providers section in ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs, login is done via

```
   public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
           OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
    }
```